# Using pyranges library, How to check if a chromosome position is contained in any interval?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, vcf-variant-call-format, pyranges

I have a .vcf file containing variants information and a .bed file containing region studied information. I am using [pyranges](https://github.com/biocore-ntnu/pyranges) library to read the .bed file. I want to filter out all the variants in .vcf file that lies in the region studied intervals specified in .bed file. Since, pyranges provides a pandas dataframe, i could iterate over each row and check for containment of my variant position; But, I am looking for an API that helps me achieve this.

Example:

```
>> df = pd.DataFrame({"Chromosome": ["chr1", "chr2"], "Start": [100, 200],
...                    "End": [150, 201]})
>> pr.PyRanges(df)

+--------------+-----------+-----------+
| Chromosome   |     Start |       End |
| (category)   |   (int32) |   (int32) |
|--------------+-----------+-----------|
| chr1         |       100 |       150 |
| chr2         |       200 |       201 |
+--------------+-----------+-----------+
```

Is there an API to find if a chromosome position 125 for chromosome "chr1" lies in any of the interval.
In above case it will be True because 125 lies in interval 100 - 150.

Comment: You may want to read [ask]

Comment: Use [pandas.cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) to bin your data.

Comment: @Robert Thanks for the reference, I had a look at the blog and tried to make the question more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gr = pr.PyRanges(df)
gr['chr1', 125:126]
```